# Updating counters in a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using an empty results dictionary with initial values 0 which I would like to update upon occurrence  once going through my source data. The Dictionary looks like this:

```
{
  "Group1": {
    "1": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "6": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "not_specified": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "Group2": {
    "1": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "6": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    },
    "not_specified": {
      "fr": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "nl": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      },
      "not_specified": {
        "answered": 0,
        "unanswered": 0
      }
    }
  }
}dic
```

When I try to update just a given counter though like:

```
myDic['Group1']['1']['nl']['answered']=myDic['Group1']['1']['nl']['answered']+10
myDic['Group2']['1']['nl']['answered']=myDic['Group2']['1']['nl']['unanswered']+100
```

I get absolutely all counters updated in the whole dictionary with the same values. What is the reason for that?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce "*all counters updated in the whole dictionary with the same values*" part.

Comment: may be you have created the dictionary by copying the reference

Comment: A Reference would be my guess as well. When Ih run your code on my machine, I get exactly the result that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is valid, but looks like your `{"answered": 0, "unanswered": 0}` dict is a reference to the same object, so when you've change the value in one it changes everywhere.

Check if `id(myDic['Group1']['1']['nl']) == id(myDic['Group1']['1']['fr'])`?
If so, you need to use `from copy import deepcopy` when created these dicts.

This code smells but makes clear overview:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

original = deepcopy(myDic['Group1']['1']['nl'])
original['answered'] += 10
myDic['Group1']['1']['nl'] = original
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, the last dictionary is a reference!